# Please help identify this rack-mount case

Tags: production

Can anyone point me to where I can find something like this?  I have a Smartview 4K monitor, and I'd like a good way to carry it around.  It seems like all of the other boxes I've looked at open on the small side and don't have the hinge.  This image came from the [Blackmagic design website](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/smartview4k/workflow).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a long time since you asked this and likely no longer need it, but in case anyone else comes across this thread looking for the same kind of case (as I did!), look for "pop up" rackmount cases for audio mixers.

Comment: Yeah, those were the closest I could find at the time, and I would probably still be interested, but I couldn't find any that tilted more than 20 degrees or so.  If you could direct me to something I could see from across the room, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks!  Side note:  I actually called and asked BMD about this.  They said the picture on the website was created by their marketing dept.